# Extract maximum number from a string

Tags: string, excel, numbers, vba

I am trying to extract all numbers from a string with a function in Excel.
In the second time, I would like to extract the maximum value contains in the string.

**My string look likes**:
ATCG=12.5,TTA=2.5,TGC=60.28

**Desired output:** 60.28

In a first time, I am trying to extract all numbers with my function but it stops only on the first figure.

```
Function MyCode(ByVal txt As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\d.+"
        If .test(txt) Then MyCode = .Execute(txt)(0)
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your decimal separator may be different from the US decimal separator.

```
Public Function MyCode(ByVal txt As String) As String
Dim maxi As Double, db As Double
maxi = -9 ^ 9
arr = Split(txt, ",")
For Each a In arr
  If InStr(a, "=") Then
    a = Mid(a, InStr(a, "=") + 1)
    ar = Replace(a, ".", Format(0, "."))
    If IsNumeric(ar) Then
        db = ar
        If db > maxi Then maxi = db: ok = True
    End If
  End If
Next a
If ok = True Then
 MyCode = CStr(maxi)
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some **VBA** *(not vbscript)* that you can adapt to you needs:

```
Public Function MyCode(ByVal txt As String) As String
    Dim maxi As Double, db As Double
    maxi = -9999
    arr = Split(Replace(txt, "=", ","), ",")
    For Each a In arr
        If IsNumeric(a) Then
            db = CDbl(a)
            If db > maxi Then maxi = db
        End If
    Next a
    MyCode = CStr(maxi)
End Function
```

[image]

NOTE:

This gives a `String` and not a `Number`.

**EDIT#1:**

In Excel-VBA, the code must be placed in a **standard module**.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=MyCode(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Hi Gary, thx for your code. It doesn't work at my side, got in output #NOM?. Maybe the version of my Excel

Comment: @user979974  I assume that your **#NOM?** is the same as my **#NAME?**.  See my **EDIT#1.**

Comment: yes same as #NAME?. I did as you advice me in your edit, and it returns me -9999. I am using Excel 2003. That's weird it works at your side not mine :-(

Comment: @user979974  getting -9999 means the macro cannot find any numeric sub-strings.  Make sure you are pointing at a "good" cell.

Comment: I used the function on this string: ATCG=12.5,TTA=2.5,TGC=60.28

Comment: @user979974  did you point to a cell or use **=MyCode("ATCG=12.5,TTA=2.5,TGC=60.28 ")**

Comment: I pointed on a cell A1 which contains the string ATCG=12.5,TTA=2.5,TGC=60.28 by doing MyCode(A1)

Comment: @user979974  It is behaving like it does not see the **.** as a decimal separator??

Comment: Yes exactly, it doesn't recognize the point as a decimal separator. If I change the point by comma it recognizes

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need VBA for this if you have a version of Excel (2010+) that includes the `AGGREGATE` function, you can do it with a worksheet formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"=",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),1)
```

where **seq_99** is a Named Formula that refers to:

```
=IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

The function results in an array, some of the values are numeric; the `AGGREGATE` function returns the largest value in the array, ignoring errors.

***The formulas below are for earlier versions of Excel and must be entered as array formulas, by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula.***

If you have 2007, you can use `IFERROR`

```
=MAX(IFERROR(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),"=",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),0))
```

For earlier versions, you can use:

```
=MAX(IF(ISERROR(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",REPT(" ",99)),"=",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))),0,--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",REPT(" ",99)),"=",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect all of the mixed numbers as doubles in an array and return the maximum value.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0    '<~~this is the default but I've included it because it has to be 0

Function maxNums(str As String)
    Dim n As Long, nums() As Variant
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    maxNums = vbNullString

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "\d*\.\d*"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            'resize the nums array to accept the matches
            ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
            'populate the nums array with the matches
            For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                nums(n) = CDbl(cmat.Item(n))
            Next n
            'test array
            'Debug.Print Join(nums, ", ")
            'return the maximum value found
            maxNums = Application.Max(nums)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I tried your script, unfortunatly, when I apply maxNums(A2), I have in output #VALUE

Comment: Well TBH, I never photoshop my results so if you *'have in output #VALUE'* then I suggest a stop, some watches and F8 to step through.