# How to find the highest and lowest values in a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the highest and lowest values of a single cell.

There are many variations to the strings

Cell E9

```
a)63Ra b)64Ra c)65Ra d)62Ra e)61Ra f)63Ra g)60Ra h)62Ra
```

Cell E10

```
a)45° b)44.5° c)45° d)45° e)45.2° f)44.7°
```

Cell E11

```
a)Ø14.290 b)Ø14.286 c)Ø14.283
```

Cell F9 > 65

Cell G9 > 60

Cell F10 > 44.5

Cell G10 > 45.2

Cell F11 > 14.290

Cell G11 > 14.283

I found a similar problem but I am not sure how to tweak the formula to my needs. [Extract maximum number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610932/extract-maximum-number-from-a-string)

Comment: You should compare only the numbers in the cells, removing the special characters, right? One cell contains all the values? I dont really understand.

Comment: Yes I want only the numbers to be extracted, I'll edit the post now to show how it should be extracted

Comment: Then apply the Regular Expression in Macro.

Comment: You have all those numbers a)63Ra b)64Ra c)65Ra d)62Ra e)61Ra f)63Ra g)60Ra h)62Ra stored in one cell? Or each value stored in a cell?

Comment: Yes a)63Ra b)64Ra c)65Ra d)62Ra e)61Ra f)63Ra g)60Ra h)62Ra is stored in 1 cell

Answer (score 1):

Try this vba code

```
 Option Explicit
Sub cut_my_number_Please()
Dim reg As Object
Dim MY_match
Dim Matches
Dim my_max As Double: my_max = -1
Dim i%, lr%: lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(3).Row
Dim k%: k = 6
Union(Range("D9:D50"), Range("F9:R50")).ClearContents
Set reg = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
With reg
.Pattern = "([\d\.]+)"
.Global = True
End With
 For i = 9 To lr
    If reg.test(Range("E" & i)) Then
      Set Matches = reg.Execute(Range("E" & i))
       For Each MY_match In Matches
         Cells(i, k) = MY_match * 1
         If MY_match * 1 >= my_max Then my_max = MY_match * 1
        k = k + 1
       Next
    End If
     Cells(i, "D") = my_max
     my_max = -1
      k = 6
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Great @Salim  Hasbaya.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for Cell E9. Hope this will help you to get an idea.

Please insert module and copy the below VBA code into that.

```
Public Function SplitText(pWorkRng As Range, pIsNumber As Boolean) As String
'Updateby Extendoffice
Dim xLen As Long
Dim xStr As String
xLen = VBA.Len(pWorkRng.Value)
For i = 1 To xLen
    xStr = VBA.Mid(pWorkRng.Value, i, 1)
    If ((VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) And pIsNumber) Or (Not (VBA.IsNumeric(xStr)) And Not (pIsNumber))) Then
        SplitText = SplitText + xStr
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Then use below function to identify highest value from the same.

```
=MAX(IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>1,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),1,2),0),IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>3,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),3,2),0),IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>5,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),5,2),0),,IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>7,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),7,2),0),IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>9,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),9,2),0),IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>11,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),11,2),0),IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>13,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),13,2),0),IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>15,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),15,2),0),IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>17,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),17,2),0),IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>19,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),19,2),0),IF(LEN(SplitText(E9,TRUE))>21,+MID(SplitText(E9,TRUE),21,2),0))
```

For lowest value use MIN().