# How to Split a Cell Numbers as Two Digits in Same Cell along with Coma?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a cell with bunch of numbers, in that need to separate as Two Digits in a cell along with Coma (,)

Ex. `A2 = 6364656261636062`

Answer: `B2 = 63,64,65,62,61,63,60,62`

And then need to find highest and lowest value from the same as

`Highest = 65 in C2` and `Lowest = 60 in D2`

please help to get it through formula or VBA.

Comment: Is this a one-time thing, or will you have multiple cells in a column with varying lengths?

Comment: having multiple cells in a column with varying lengths, Is there anything possible thorough VBA?

Comment: You can always apply the formula through VBA. I was asking, because it would be possible to use Text to Columns, using a fixed length width for multiple columns, but it may be a little unwieldy if you have a lot of various text to do it with.

Comment: could you please share the VBA code, let me try to work on it. else few person already answered let me try based on that. I just need an hint to fix it

Comment: please refer below link for exact question. Need an answer for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56680470/how-to-find-the-highest-and-lowest-values-in-a-single-cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the concatenated text you can use `TEXTJOIN`, and `MID` in an array combination:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,MID(A2,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)/2))+ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)/2))-1,2))
```

Formula in `C2`:

```
=MAX(--MID(A2,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A;,LEN(A2)/2))+ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)/2))-1,2))
```

Formula in `D2`:

```
=MIN(--MID(A2,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A;,LEN(A2)/2))+ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)/2))-1,2))
```

All formulas need to be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Note:**

If you don't have `TEXTJOIN`, you could use:

```
=LEFT(CONCAT(MID(A2,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)/2))+ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)/2))-1,2)&","),LEN(A2)+((LEN(A2)/2))-1)
```

Again, enter as array formula! Also, screenshot shows wrong result, that's fixed.

Comment: Great, It's seems easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, the formula would be like:

```
=+CONCATENATE(MID(A2,1,2),IF(LEN(A2)>3,",",""),MID(A2,3,2),IF(LEN(A2)>5,",",""),MID(A2,5,2),IF(LEN(A2)>7,",",""),MID(A2,7,2),IF(LEN(A2)>9,",",""),MID(A2,9,2),IF(LEN(A2)>11,",",""),MID(A2,11,2),IF(LEN(A2)>13,",",""),MID(A2,13,2),IF(LEN(A2)>15,",",""),MID(A2,15,2),IF(LEN(A2)>17,",",""),MID(A2,17,2),IF(LEN(A2)>19,",",""),MID(A2,19,2),IF(LEN(A2)>21,",",""),MID(A2,21,2))
```

For the second section you need a helper column to put each value on a different cell and then use MAX() and MIN() or use VBA.

Comment: Could you please send VBA Script. because when i am using MAX() or MIN() which is giving error.

Comment: What about `=MAX(IF(LEN(A2)>1,+MID(A2,1,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>3,+MID(A2,3,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>5,+MID(A2,5,2),0),,IF(LEN(A2)>7,+MID(A2,7,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>9,+MID(A2,9,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>11,+MID(A2,11,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>13,+MID(A2,13,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>15,+MID(A2,15,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>17,+MID(A2,17,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>19,+MID(A2,19,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>21,+MID(A2,21,2),0))`

Comment: Jerry, seems you're posting your answer in comments. requesting you to post it as answer, because of that people can easily find and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can  use  the regular expression with Pattern (\d{2}). Suppose that your data is in column(A), Starting From A2
Use this Macro

```
Option Explicit
Sub cut_my_number_Please()
Dim reg As Object
Dim MY_match, Matches, My_String$
Dim My_Max As Double: My_Max = -1
Dim My_Min As Double: My_Min = 100
Dim i%, lr%: lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row

Range("c2").Resize(lr, 3).ClearContents
Set reg = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")

With reg
.Pattern = "(\d{2})"
.Global = True
End With

 For i = 2 To lr
   If reg.test(Range("A" & i)) Then
      Set Matches = reg.Execute(Range("A" & i))
      For Each MY_match In Matches
          My_String = My_String & MY_match & ";"
        If MY_match * 1 >= My_Max Then _
        My_Max = MY_match * 1
        If MY_match * 1 < My_Min Then _
        My_Min = MY_match * 1
      Next MY_match
        Range("C" & i) = Mid(My_String, 1, Len(My_String) - 1)
        Range("D" & i) = My_Max
        Range("E" & i) = My_Min
    End If
     My_Min = 100: My_Max = -1: My_String = ""
 Next i
  Range("D1") = "Max Of My Serial"
  Range("E1") = "Min Of My Serial"
End Sub
```

Comment: Great Mastro !!

Comment: Thank you Regiz,
You can see my two array formulas bellow for max and Min

Comment: I'm sorry above not bellow

Comment: It's Okay! Dude !! No Issue's. you're a Mastro !!

Answer (score 0):

IN THE CELL C2 THIS ARRAY FORMULA (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

```
=MAX(--(IF(MID($A2,2*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))))-1,2)="",0,MID($A2,2*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))))-1,2))))
```

IN THE CELL C3 THIS ARRAY FORMULA (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

```
=MIN(--(IF(MID($A2,2*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))))-1,2)="",1000,MID($A2,2*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))))-1,2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Jerry.

```
=MAX(IF(LEN(A2)>1,+MID(A2,1,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>3,+MID(A2,3,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>5,+MID(A2,5,2),0),,IF(LEN(A2)>7,+MID(A2,7,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>9,+MID(A2,9,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>11,+MID(A2,11,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>13,+MID(A2,13,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>15,+MID(A2,15,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>17,+MID(A2,17,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>19,+MID(A2,19,2),0),IF(LEN(A2)>21,+MID(A2,21,2),0))
```

Thanks for it @Jerry Jeremiah.